# Why I have this error with swift mail php

Tags: php, email

I have configured SwiftMailer with theses params but when I try to send a mail I have an error.

Code:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587,'tls')
    ->setUsername('mail@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('password');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

Swift::init('swiftmailer_configurator');
// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    // Give the message a subject
    ->setSubject($sujet)
    // Set the From address with an associative array
    ->setFrom(array('Mail@mail.com' => 'Site Mail'))
    // Set the To addresses with an associative array
    ->setTo(array($mail))
    // Give it a body
    ->setBody($texte)
    // And optionally an alternative body
    ->addPart("<q>$texte</q>", 'text/html');

// Send the message
if ($mailer->send($message)) {
    echo "Sent";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Result:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
>   message ' in
>   C:\wamp\www\mail\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php
>   on line 383 ( ! ) Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250
>   but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not
>   accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 e69sm88886wma.2 - gsmtp "
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\mail\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php
>   on line 383

Comment: Did you even read the error message?!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says,

> 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

You need to authorize the use of Gmail for external applications: go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps then change `Access for less secure apps` to `enabled`.

If it's still not working, you can follow the advises given on [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257).

Comment: @herbethadrien Have you followed the other advices given on the help page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem by using my pro mail istead of my personal mail